# How to create a new log every each day

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am newbie in node.js and want to create new log/debug file on each day to print console.log value within it because if there is one file it become large in size and unable to view properly too.

please give me suggestion how can i do?

Any running example will appreciate me.

Comment: Are you creating log file manually or using some npm package? Can you put the code that you are executing? It would be easy to help if we know what you're doing.

Comment: Use `logrotate` or `PM2`, a process manager in Node also helps with log rotation.

Comment: var log_file = fs.createWriteStream('./debug' + timeStamp + '.log', {
    flags: 'w'
});
console.log = function(d) { //
    var dt = new Date();
    var utcDate = dt.toUTCString();
   log_file.write(utcDate + " : " + util.format(d) + '\n');
};

Comment: I am doing as per above code...

Answer (score 3):

Such element of any program is called 'logger' . Logger can easily handle your log files.

There are a lot of implementation for logging of your server

You can find any logger either `npm` or `github` or even in Google;)

for example, `npm install winston`

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

```
  var winston = require('winston');

  winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
  winston.info('Hello again distributed logs');

  winston.level = 'debug';
  winston.log('debug', 'Now my debug messages are written to console!');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to rotate log based on size of the log file, using size you can do it as given below.

You can use [logrotate-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logrotate-stream) for this.

1. Install it globally using `npm install -g logrotate-stream`
2. Run your server using `node app.js 2>&1 | logrotate-stream app.log --keep 5 --size '1m' --compress`

**Explanation**

`2>&1`  send stderr to stdout ([detail about `2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean))

`|`  pipe output(here stderr and stdout) to next command as input (here `logrotate-stream`)

`app.log` log file name

`--keep 5` maximum number of file to keep

`--size 1m` maximum size of each file in mb
`--compmress` compress files

**Log files will look like this**

```
app.log
app.log.0.gz
app.log.1.gz
app.log.2.gz
app.log.3.gz
app.log.4.gz
```

Comment: Thanks but still unable to create log file for each day.

Comment: thanks for everyone but I found its by another way and its working properly.

Comment: /*test1.js*/   var fs = require('fs'); var logs = require('tracer').colorConsole({ format : "{{timestamp}} <{{title}}>: {{message}} ==>> (in {{file}}:{{line}})", dateformat : "yyyy_mm_dd_hh:MM:ss TT", transport : function(log) { console.log(log.output); var timestamp = log.timestamp.substring(0,10); fs.open('./debug.' + timestamp + '.log', 'a', function(err, fileId) { fs.write(fileId, log.output + "\n", null, 'utf8', function() { fs.close(fileId, function() { }); }); }); } }); module.exports = logs;

Comment: /*test2.js*/            var logger = require('./loggerFile.js');  
setInterval(function() {
    test();
}, 2 * 60 * 1000);
function test(){
logger.debug("inside test function.");
logger.info("within if condition.");
logger.error("this is not an error.");
}